# Capistrano deployment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I am a neophyte in ruby app deployment.

I am trying to deploy my app named "bookshop" on Capistrano.
I have already uploaded my application on github having following link "git@github.com:my_account_name/bookshop.git"

When I am doing "cap deploy:setup", I am getting the following error:

```
servers: ["localhost"]
connection failed for: localhost (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))
```

Any help would be appreciated

My "deployment.rb" file:

```
set :application, "bookshop"

set :domain,"localhost"
server domain, :web, :app

default_run_options[:pty]= true
set :use_sudo, false

set :aplication,"localhost"

set :scm, :git
set :user, 'bookshop.com'
set :deploy_to, "/home/www/bookshop"
set :repository, "git@github.com:my_account_name/bookshop.git"

role :web, "localhost"                          # Your HTTP #server, Apache/etc
role :app, "localhost"                          # This may be the #same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "localhost", :primary => true # This is where #Rails migrations will run

 namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
 end
```

Comment: Are you running a web server and database on your machine?

Comment: web server yes m running .... how i need database ... Can you please tell me all the steps ..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ssh agent enabled in your machine.

Comment: web server yes m running .... how i need database ... Can you please tell me all the steps ...